# Is it possible to combine chrome extension and chrome native client and distribute them as single unit

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I would like to create a new Chrome extension which will be distributed via Chrome store. I also would like to port some code parts of this extension to native code and to use Chrome's native client for it.

So my questions - is it possible to create solution which

- comprises of two components - Chrome extension (e.g. can embed content scripts to third party sites like google.com) and native client (e.g. run some native code).
- should have these two components be able to interact with each other e.g. via message passing (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)
- is distributed via Chrome Store as a single unit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are two similarly named but quite different technologies.

1. **Native Hosts.** Those are separate programs, that cannot be distributed in the Web Store, and talk to your JavaScript with [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), a variant of standard Messaging API.
2. **Native Client modules ([NaCl/PNaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/overview)).** Those work like browser plugins, and they can be bundled with the extension.

   Note that they are sandboxed from the system - the idea here is performance gain or non-trivial non-HTML UI inside the browser.

   Inside your extension, you create an `<embed>` element that creates an instance of your native code module. [JavaScript code can interact with (P)NaCl code](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/message-system) with DOM events.

   [This page](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing) contains a guide on using NaCl in Chrome Apps, and mentions that the same applies to extensions. I haven't seen any better documentation, so you'll need to experiment and search around a bit.